# Support of $x$ also belonging to the set of best responses when $x$ is a best reponse

Tags: functions, game-theory

If $ \mathbf x $ belongs to the set of best responses to $\mathbf y$ i.e. to $BR(\mathbf y) = arg max \mathbf x \cdot A \mathbf y$, why do all of the pure strategies in the support of $\mathbf x $ also belong to  $BR(\mathbf y)$?